# Will multiple identical prototype object generated in this case?

Tags: javascript, prototype

For example, the js code is:

```
function Fruit() {this.type = "fruit";};
function Apple() {this.name = "apple"; this.__proto__ = new Fruit();}
```

If I call `new Apple()` multiple times, will same amount of `new Fruit()` be generated? Or it depends on the implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it won't.

As prototype is shared by all objects. Any object of apple would have a prototype similar to that of Fruit, but each time new fruit object would not be created.

But setting _proto is a bad practice. Instead you can do it as

```
Apple.prototype=Object.create(Fruit.prototype)
```

Both does have same effect.

For reference: [proto reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto).